# How to set drawable on screen when app is in background?

Tags: android

Now I have this blue screen when app is in background, I want to change this blue screen to another drawable screen. How can I do this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeuR6.jpg)

I use this:

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mBinding.getRoot().setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.checkmark));
    mBinding.fragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

and my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data></data>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/authorized"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/green" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_up_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/authorized"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I just have white screen when app is in background.

Answer (score 1):

Yeap Its possible with `onPause()`

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    containerRoot.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this , R.color.blue));
    containerBody.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

**Step 1:** 
 
Set BackgroundColor in your root layout

 
**Step 2:** 
 
Set Visibility to GONE in your body layout

**EDIT**

```
containerRoot.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.my_drawable));
```

Comment: I need to set drawable background, not background color, and your solution doesn't work for me

Comment: @MihailMalahov see my edit , no problem use R.drawable.name instead of R.color.name

Comment: I just have white background when I  follow your advice

Comment: can you update your question with code samples